# How to build for Android 5 using Framework7?

Tags: android, html-framework-7

The sample app just hangs on the splash screen when deployed to a Samsung Note3 running Android 5.0.  Is there something special that I'm missing?

Using Framework7 cli 3.1.0 and Framework7 5.3.0.  Created app using:

```
framework7 create --ui
```

Selected options were Cordova App, Framework7 core, tabbed view, Webpack, no CSS pre-processor, include FW7 icons.

App was installed on device with:

```
npm run build-dev-cordova & f7 cordova run android
```

The app works fine on a tablet running Android 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add [cordova-plugin-webview-checker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-webview-checker) plugin and set by JavaScript a link to [Android System Webview on Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.webview) for update it, according to the requirements of your app (also if very basic, as this one).

Otherwise you can consider exploring Chromium, maybe you can profit of the following tracks in further cases:

- https://www.chromium.org/developers/androidwebview to understand what you need
- https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview#what_version_of_chrome_is_it_based_on_ to understand what to expect from OS

Answer (score 0):

Update Android System Webview.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.webview&hl=en_US

Unfortunately, I don't know of a way to have this update automatically with installation of a Cordova app.